# What is the easiest way to obtain an heirloom in Apex Legends?

Tags: apex-legends

Is it really all just luck? I have heard that there is a guaranteed heirloom after 500 packs, but I've opened a bunch- I don't know how many. Still, I was wondering what I can do to raise my chances without wasting all my money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for the easiest way to get a heirloom of your choice, then just buy 500 apex packs and you have a 100% chance of obtaining one.

If you don't want to spend $500 on a heirloom, you can also wait until an event with a heirloom is live and craft/buy all 24 items to get a guaranteed heirloom.

If you don't want to spend any money to get one, then it's just pure luck. You can create a new account and try your luck there. The first levels grant you loot boxes like crazy, I know a guy who got a heirloom on his alt account, which eventually became his main. Another way to get one free is leveling up, as you continue leveling up, you will get more packs, thus increasing your odds.